# How to draw strings on WindowsForms Picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap

I have my own simple 3d engine class (`myGraphics`) that saves its results in a Bitmap variable. 
That Bitmap is then placed in a PictureBox (`PictureBox.Image = myGraphics.bmp`)

This is working well, the problem came when i needed to mark some points on the drawing. Since there's no built in method to draw strings on bitmap, i followed solutions in similar questions and now i got a `Graphics` variable on my `myGraphics` so i can draw the numbers there. The important bits of the code are as follows:

```
public class myGraphics
{
    public Graphics g;
    public void initialize(int W, int H )
    {
        //sets some values 
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    }
    public void draw()
    {
        // code to draw on myGraphics.bmp
        markpoints();
    }
    public void markpoints() 
    {
        if (draw_points) { 
            foreach (objecto ob in solidos) {
                for (int p = 0; p < ob.viewpoints.Count; p++)
                {
                    // determine position of text (x, y)
                    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    g.DrawString(p.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10), drawBrush, x, y);
                    g.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, if i got it right, g.Flush() should merge the Graphics g on the Bitmap, but it's not working that way, so i get the right image but no stings on it.

I also tried this: `myGraphics.g = PictureBox.CreateGraphics();`to solve it. Using breakpoints in debug mode i realized that the strings do appear on the control using this method, but are erased right after, when PictureBox updates.

So, how can i solve this, so i can get the numbers displayed on the drawing?

Comment: You are modifying the bitmap but there isn't any way that the PictureBox can know this.  The Image class has no events.  So it doesn't know that it needs to repaint the image.  It is up to you to call the PictureBox' Invalidate() method, now it knows.

Comment: that was not the problem but it made me get to it, so thanks. it is kind of a silly mistake, still I will write an answer

Answer (score -2):

When the `PictureBox.Image` is updated, the graphics are cleared. Therefore, `markpoints()` must be called from outside the class, right after `PictureBox.Image` is updated.

Also, assigning `myGraphics.g = Picturebox.CreateGraphics()` wont work, changes on myGraphics.g wont be updated to the control PictureBox. The control's graphics must be updated on the paint event, passing `e.graphics` to `markpoints`

Also, `g.flush()` does not merge the graphics with the Bitmap, it is actually unnecessary for this code

So, the final solution:

```
public class myGraphics
{
    // public Graphics g is no longer necessary
    public void initialize(int W, int H ) { //sets some values}
    public void draw() { // code to draw on myGraphics.bmp }

    public void markpoints(Graphics graph) 
    {
        if (draw_points) { 
            graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graph.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            foreach (objecto ob in solidos) {
                for (int p = 0; p < ob.viewpoints.Count; p++)
                {
                    // determine position of text (x, y)
                    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    g.DrawString(p.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10), drawBrush, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Connect to picture box
myGraphics mg = new myGraphics()
Picturebox.Image = mg.bmp;
PictureBox.Invalidate(); // forces update of the control using paint event

private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    mg.markpoints(e.Graphics);
}
```

Comment: _The approach using PictureBox.CreateGraphics() is enough to solve the problem_ No, most likely it is not enough as the result will not persist.. Either draw into the Image or use the e.Graphics object from the Paint event..!

Comment: @TaW  I cant assign `e.Graphics() = myGraphics.g` because `e.Graphics` is readonly... does that mean i have to put the `markpoints()` code inside the paint event?

Comment: Yes. Or you can pass the `e.Graphics` object out to a function that uses it to do the drawing, say `markpoints(e.Graphics)`. Do note however that this must be called from the `Paint` event and you are not allowed to store or cache it as it will not be valid otherwise!

Comment: Thanks, it worked and also performs better. Should i update my answer? I'm new on SO...